# Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed. "single and double quotes are not parsing"

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop

Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed. "single and double quotes are not parsing"

```
g.V('a48543e9-d527-4928-b045-71da15a76bfe').property(single, 'title', '{'fr': '', 'en': 'Title Edit 02'}')
```

Getting error:

```
{
 "detailedMessage": "Failed to interpret Gremlin query: Query parsing failed at line 1, character position at 77, error message : no viable alternative at input 'g.V('a48543e9-d527-4928-b045-71da15a76bfe').property(single,'title','{\\'fr':'",
 "requestId": "4307b026-c0b5-45b0-9ec1-293822ee35ef",
 "code": "MalformedQueryException"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to escape your quotes or perhaps simply choose to wrap in double quotes:

```
g.V('a48543e9-d527-4928-b045-71da15a76bfe').
  property(single, 'title', "{'fr': '', 'en': 'Title Edit 02'}")
```